# Story set in 2021 where water is now manufactured?

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a sci-fi story that my mum is looking for which she read maybe 20-21 years ago. It goes something like this:

- In the year 2021 a scientist discovers a risk-free way of manufacturing water. Example: Mixing hydrogen and atoms together
- By this time the continent Africa had died off because of the lack of supplies, food and water and participation in one of five world wars for water
- Water has become the worlds next currency
- Several World Wars emerged because of the lack of water. My mum says that in the story water had run out and rain became very rare
- Several countries want this risk-free way of manufacturing water and are willing to do anything for it
- Water is power in this sci-fi story. Not like as in hydro-power, but as in power, control etc

Anyone know what this story may be?

Comment: Sounds like Tank Girl. Anything else in the story?

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty- Is tank girl a cartoon?

Comment: Graphic Novel and a poorly done movie.

Comment: Always found the movie quite okay'ish for what it tried to do.